# PhantomJs rasterization - possible to make a multipage pdf from multiple pages?

Tags: pdf, npm, phantomjs

I'm running phantom using their rasterize example script to create a single-page pdf of a page.

I have several different pages that I would like to rasterize and concatenate into a multipage pdf file. Is this possible with what is currently there or do I have to bring a tool like pdftk into the mix?

(alternately, is there another node module that I can use for this - I found pdftk-helper but it's shall we say...unfinished)

Answer (score 8):

Add to following from where you want to start a new page:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>
```

More information about this can be found here:
http://we-love-php.blogspot.be/2012/12/create-pdf-invoices-with-html5-and-phantomjs.html